# Очистка коллекции

Tags: c#

Как очистить коллекцию, если таким образом не получается сделать очистку.

```
listbox.itemsource = collect.clear();
```

Comment: что за collect? что за метод `clear`? если это должен был быть метод [`Clear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132405(v=vs.110).aspx), то он неверно записан, и кроме того, данный метод ничего не возвращает. Что значит _очистить коллекцию_? удалить все элементы? можно в itemsource просто присвоить новую пустую коллекцию

Comment: Clear() стандартный метод.

Comment: Да, удалить все элементы из коллекции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListBox никак не может узнать, что коллекцию очистили. Для этого нет никаких оповещений. В WPF при привязке коллекции ObservableCollection ListBox узнает об изменениях. В указанном же случае, если привязан обычный List или Array, нужно просто очистить коллекцию и заново передать ее в ListBox.

```
// неправильная версия (т.к. ссылка не изменилась, обновления списка не произойдет)   
    collect.clear();
    listbox.ItemsSource = collect;
```

UPD: действительно, я слегка попутал (спасибо комментаторам :) ). Очистка списка - операция дорогостоящая, ее вообще не стоит делать, а просто передать ссылку на новый пустой лист:

```
 listbox.ItemsSource = new List<string>();
```

если необходимо отфильтровать лист, а не очистить, можно сделать так:

```
listbox.ItemsSource = collect.Where(x=>условие).ToList();
```

Comment: Это сработает? Ссылка ведь остаётся старая.

Comment: @Qwertiy, действительно, такой способ не работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, все верно. обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

```
ObservableCollection<string> items = ObservableCollection<string>();
listbox.ItemsSource = items;
```

очищайте `items`. Это ссылочный тип данных, сделав так:

```
 items.Clear();
```

результат будет виден и в listbox.ItemsSource, так как ссылочные значения `listbox.ItemsSource` и `items` одинаковы.

Comment: Не всегда можно обратиться к items, вылезает предупреждение что нельзя обратиться к items и ссылается на itemssource

Comment: @SOFL, что значит не всегда можно обратиться? вы случайно не путаете listbox.Items и items?

Comment: Да, я имел ввиду свойство от контрола

Comment: понятно, очищать нужно тот items который вы создавали.